# calling library constructor in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, oop

In OOP (PHP, in my case),

```
class Hello{
    __construct($a, $b){
    return $a * $b;
    }
}
```

we pass the value to constructor as:

```
$hello = new Hello(5, 10);
```

Now, in codeigniter i have this library as Hello.

```
class Hello{
    __construct($a, $b){
    return $a * $b;
    }
}
```

and have loaded this library to my controller as

```
$this->load->library('hello');
```

How am i to pass argument on hello class for its constructor? any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html

```
$params = array('type' => 'large', 'color' => 'red');

$this->load->library('Someclass', $params);
```

Comment: i reckon what we need is large and red so why user type and color index?? cant' we just pass array('large', 'red')? if not why do we have to use index where we only want values?

Comment: You can also create an `initialize()` function if you want to pass multiple parameters. After loading the library, you would call it, and it would act like the constructor. A lot of CI's libraries do this.